# Partitions not showing up during windows XP installation

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, partitioning

Yes, I am installing windows XP as my side OS in 2019.
I will tell you what happened. I have an ISO image of windows XP.
I created a bootable flash drive using Win2Flash and booted the usb on the same pc. I chose the part 1 of installation, everything was going well until when the setup asked me for the partition to install windows XP in. Only one partition was shown , which was the usb flash drive.
My PC already had a handful of partitions including one free for installing it.You know that I can't install windows XP on my usb drive,so the question is:
How do I make my partitions show up during installation?
Thanks for reading, I'll see if I get the solution before you give the answer.(I didn't find it yet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Windows 7 install see my new SATA drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/199689/why-cant-windows-7-install-see-my-new-sata-drive)

Comment: If you need a "side OS" then install Ubuntu or any other desktop Linux.

Comment: I am installing it for retro games. I am a fan of all of them and I think modern games suck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Windows XP on modern desktop/laptop.

will require additional drivers for SATA integrated into the iso

While XP was introduced, IDE bus was the norm, SATA was new.

Same scenario applies for USB3 drivers for windows7 iso

Comment: And XP doesn't support UEFI mode or installation in GPT drives. In summary, it's a ridiculous project and potentially dangerous for the user and others if ever connected to the internet.

Comment: i agree on the uefi support part, but why dangerous for the user and others ?

Comment: Except a very recent patch due to the severity of the vulnerability, XP  hasn't received  security updates in the last 5 years.

Comment: Thanks! I determined the SATA driver I need and integrated it into the installation files with NLite. This small info really helped!

Answer (score 0):

WinSetupFromUSB and Easy2Boot both include SATA\RAID\SCSI XP 32-bit drivers.
You just add the XP install ISO to the USB drive and then boot from the USB drive, the correct Mass Storage Driver will automatically be added (unless very new PC which has no available XP drivers).